# How to make a seamless transition between translucent StatusBar and ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-statusbar

I tried to play with colors, but then the border becomes sharper.

[image]

My styles.xml

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <!-- system_bar_background_semi_transparent 40% black -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#66000000</item>
</style>
```

PS: screenshot from the emulator (Android 9, API level 28), I can not test on a real device.

Answer (score 1):

The look of status bar with `android:windowTranslucentStatus` is controlled by system. The attribute exists since Kitkat, where it would cause a gradient from black top to transparent bottom. On AOSP Lollipop this is replaced by solid `#44000000` but can't be relied upon as different manufacturers implement this differently. E.g. my late Xperia L used the same implementation as Kitkat.

If you want complete control of the status bar color use the following combination of attributes instead:

```
<!-- Make the app responsible for drawing status bar and navigation bar backgrounds. -->
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
<!-- Change the status bar background to whatever you want. -->
<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">#6000</item>
```

The dark space behind translucent objects is caused by shadow from elevation. Shadow is drawn behind the whole object not just around it. You can remove the shadow from action bar like this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.ActionBar.Translucent</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
    <!-- While at it you can keep normal primary color and change just the action bar background here. -->
    <item name="background">#6000</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason it does not work for me (nothing changed).

Comment: Did you remove `android:windowTranslucentStatus`?

Comment: Hmmm... Color changes successfully. When I choose the opaque color everything is fine (seamless). But if I choose a translucent color - the problem still exists: https://i.imgur.com/r9QHMXM.png (both #CECECECE)

Comment: Oh, right! The action bar needs to have zero elevation. Check out the updated answer.